# Using Overflow with Tablebuilder

Tags: php, css, overflow, html-table

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a lengthy table less bulky (so it doesn't stretch the page so much), and my current idea is to just use the overflow property so that that max height for this table is 800px, and the rest you scroll to see. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to go about doing this while using the tablebuilder class, so I'm hoping to get some help.

Here is where the table is built;

```
$title = new Comment("{$mysidia->input->get("user")}'s Cats");
$title->setBold(TRUE);
$title->setHeading(2);
$document->add($title);
$adoptTable = new TableBuilder("otheradopttable", 640);
$adoptTable->setAlign(new Align("center", "middle"));
$adoptTable->buildHeaders("Image", "Name", "Breed", "Play");
$stmt = $mysidia->db->select("owned_adoptables", array("aid"), "owner = '{$mysidia->input->get("user")}'");
while($id = $stmt->fetchColumn()){
    $adopt = new OwnedAdoptable($id);
    $cells = new LinkedList;
    $cells->add(new TCell(new Comment("<img src='{$adopt->getImage()}'/>")));
    $cells->add(new TCell("{$adopt->getName()}"));
    $cells->add(new TCell("{$adopt->getDescription()}"));
    $cells->add(new TCell(new Comment("<a href='http://catisserie.mysidiahost.com/levelup/click/{$adopt->getAdoptID()}'>Play</a>")));
    $adoptTable->buildRow($cells);
}
$document->add($adoptTable);
```